# One radiator is not getting hot (water doesn't seem to flow through it)

Tags: plumbing, water, heating, central-heating, radiator

Central heating system is Pressurised system with Combi-boiler. My fix attempts so far:

1. Bleeding air out of the one radiator (with a bleed key). Immediately bled water implying no problem.
2. Checked thermostatic valve (e.g. pin not stuck).
3. Checked unbalanced system: in particular, I turned off all other radiators in my house to try and force a flow through the one radiator, but still it does not work.
4. Flushed sludge from radiator: Took the radiator of the wall, took it outside and attached a hose to it to flush the sludge out - a lot of sludge was expelled so was hopeful this may fix it. Indeed when I reattached it to the wall, opened the valves to let the water through (as well as topping up the pressure in the entire system) the radiator got a little hot, but unfortunately quickly got cold (the pipes to/from the radiator also got hot then cold, perhaps indicating that the radiator is not requesting water?)

So I'm a bit stuck about what to do next - I'll likely try flushing the one radiator again to see if there is more sludge in there, but any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: use a bucket and keep bleeding for few minutes to get the air bulb out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was lots of sludge in the pipe to the radiator that was not allowing water to flow into it. Blasting this out using the pressurised system + loosening it with a long stick fixed it.